# Drupal cannot see changes

Tags: drupal

I'm a drupal beginner.
I have to edit my home page, and nothing wrong with it, but when i log out I cannot see the page changes I made before.
It seems that the edits are just on my admin profile, how can I make it visible for everyone?

Comment: Sorry for not being more exhaustive, but I'm getting nervous ahahah

Comment: Solved, it was a caching problem.
Answer found here https://www.drupal.org/node/318576

Comment: Drupal (can) cache content, CSS, JS, list of used template files... so when ever you change something and don't see your change on front-end first thing you should try is clearing the cache.